# Bash script expression syntax crash in loop

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

im have a script which puts the output of "df" into a string.
When the script runs once everything is fine, but when i put it in a while loop, it crashs in the second run with the following error.

cut: invalid field value ‘\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6’
Try 'cut --help' for more information.
./getdata.sh: line 248: 1
2
3
4
5
6%6: syntax error in expression (error token is "2
3
4
5
6%6")

Code snippet:

```
    PARTITION_RETURN_STRING=""
PARTITION_TEMP_STRING=""
for i in $(df | awk '{ print $6 }')
do
        if [ "$i" != "Mounted" ]; then
                for abc in $(seq 1 6)
                do
                        PARTITION_TEMP_STRING=$(df -m | awk -v bla=$i '$6 == bla' | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f $abc)
                        PARTITION_RETURN_STRING="$PARTITION_RETURN_STRING$PARTITION_TEMP_STRING"
                        if [ "$(($abc%6))" = "0" ]; then
                                PARTITION_RETURN_STRING+="|"
                        else
                                PARTITION_RETURN_STRING+="#"
                        fi
                done
        fi
done
```

Seems like there is a value which is getting used in the first run and didnt resets for the second run, but i couldnt figure it out.

Comment: Try running your code under `set -xv` to see what's going on.

Comment: ...which is to say, `PS4=':$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO+' bash -x yourscript` will give you line-by-line trace logs so you can identify more narrowly what went wrong and ask a tighter question.

Comment: There's a bunch of kibitzing that could be done about code in here not being good-practice ([DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor), [Quoting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes), [inappropriate use of all-caps variable names](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html)), but without trace logs it's hard to say exactly what the immediate cause of the issue is. (BTW, consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ to get warnings about missing quoting).

Comment: You probably have a modified `IFS` that prevents `for` from splitting the values of `$(seq 1 6)` correctly, so `$abc` is worth `1\n2\n...6` and `cut` complains that's not a valid value for the `-f` option. I reproduced the IFS/for/seq behaviour [here](https://ideone.com/uRIKlQ)

Comment: Seems like this entire code snippet could be re-written as `df -m | sed -e 1d | tr -s ' ' | tr ' \n' '#|'`

Comment: (It doesn't show well in the comment, but that last cmd is `tr ' \n' '#|'` where the first argument is a space and a `\n`)

Comment: @william-pursell Oh. I thought it was more `df | awk '/\//{printf "%s#%s#%s#%s#%s#%s|",$6,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5}'`, so with the partition name in front.

Comment: `for ((abc=1; abc<=6; abc++)); do` as a replacement for the `seq` use is appropriate, then. (I almost called out the use of `seq` among my listing of obvious bad practices above; kicking myself for not going there earlier).

Comment: There's no _while loop_ posted.